# Usage of "could" in past to indicate "statements of fact"

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs

I am aware of the usage of COULD in the following cases (list from Cambridge Grammar (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/modals-and-modality/could)):

- possibility in the present and the future.
- suggestions and permissions
- past ability
- past single events with verbs of senses and mental processes

Also, this makes clear that sentences like "I could visit you yesterday but I was lazy" or "He could travel to China a week ago" are incorrect.

But then the are sentences like:

- Hundreds of years ago, even a simple injury could be fatal.
- In the ancient Rome, you could have both male and female lovers and nobody wondered.

For the following examples, I was told that these are statements of fact:

- I could buy it yesterday and I did.
- Back then, travelling could be dangerous.

What usage of "could"would that be? I cannot see a fitting case in the overview. Why those are correct even when "COULD" refer to the past events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A simple injury could be fatal** is past possibility or past capability. Not all simple injuries were fatal, but one could be. It is not a simple statement of fact that all injuries, even simple ones, were fatal hundreds of years ago.  If you had a simple injury it **might** prove fatal. It was capable of killing you.

**you could have both male and female lovers** again refers to a past possibility or a past capability. Gender was not an irrelevancy in all love relationships in ancient Rome, but it was possibly an irrelevancy. Gender could be irrelevant as far as people were concerned. A person was capable (not prevented by societal taboo) of having lovers of either gender.

Comment: So are you saying the first sentence is not correct? I made those up. My point is - the grammar source I linked does not list this usage for COULD, or maybe it is implied by some of the entries? I mean, I guess I should not say "A simple injury could have been fatal" in this case, or "might have been" in your case.

Comment: No, I am not saying it is incorrect.  I'm saying that the first sentence about simple injuries falls into the first category in your bulleted list.

Comment: Well but you mention "past" possibility, while the grammar there confines this to present and future possibilities (more details in the link I put in the question).

Comment: I don't think that grammar page "confines" anything. It is a quick and dirty listing, not presenting itself as the final word on the subject.

Comment: What I am trying to understand is - according to that grammar guide, I should not use "could" for past possibilities. But using "could have" changes the sense, in my opinion.

Comment: You are misguided when treating it as a compendious list of all possible usages. It isn't.

Comment: So this additional meaning somehow refers to a general possibility in the past, correct? For a specific possibility, "could have" needs to be used, as in "I could have done it yesterday" (not I could do it yesterday). This "general past possibility" is something my other grammar book suggests, but with no examples.

Comment: **I could do it yesterday** means you were able to do it yesterday. *I don't know why I can't jump over this fence. I could do it yesterday.*   **I could have done it yesterday** means that doing it was possible for you yesterday.  *Sorry, I can't meet with you today. I have other obligations. I could have done it yesterday, but you were busy.*

Comment: Yes, in the "capability" sense, I understand that usage of "could".  But in the other sense it does not work I think - "I could buy it yesterday" when I want to express "I had a chance to buy it / it was possible for me".

Comment: Right, if you want to express the idea of *opportunity to do something* rather than the innate capability of doing it, **could have bought** is the proper choice, not **could buy**.  *I could have bought that car yesterday when I looked at it. But I delayed, and now someone else has bought it.*

Comment: Thank you, I think your explanation with those 2 examples is the missing piece as it covers the "general past possibility" that my other book mentions but that Cambridge list misses. I have added two more examples in the original question, if you could be so kind and take a look.